# migrate drupal site , error occured, the site was down

Tags: migrations

I migrate my site from WinServer2003 to CentOS ,  with the following step:
1. migrate the database to the CentOS server with .sql files backup.
2.copy all the website root file to the new server.

when i  visited some node an error occured:

[image: the error]

according to the message  there was a table or view was missing, but there was no such a table or view in the old system(win2003)

how can i fix the problem, any suggestions are appreciated, Thanks in advanced.

when i do some config (i delete the text format: filter HTML), the site  was completely down.
 when visit it just show an error:
[image: the error two]

i am really confused.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem,  the link : https://www.drupal.org/node/1882292  i just follow the #11 's method and create the image_dimensions table.